# Finding the number of triples $(a,b,c)$ with $-47 \leq a,b,c \leq 47$ and $a+b+c >0$

Tags: combinatorics

> Kate is looking for ordered triples $(a,b,c)$ of distinct integers such that $-47 \leq \; a,b,c \; \leq 47$ and $a+b+c>0$. How many such ordered triples can Kate find?

My first step was to let  $a_1=a+47, \; b_1=b+47$ and $c_1=c+47$ so that $a_1+b_1+c_1>141$ and  $0 \leq \; a,b,c \; \leq 94$. Do I simply have to solve for all $a_1+b_1+c_1=142, \; 143, \cdots, 282$ and sum these results. Or is there a better way?

You can solve the above sub problems using a stars and bars method http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Plain Stars and Bars does  not quite work here. The integers are supposed to be **distinct**, and plain Stars and Bars pays no attention to that. (It can be adjusted.)

But we will not use it. We count the triples $(a,b,c)$ such that $a\lt b\lt c$, then multiply by $3!$.

Adding $47$ sounds like a good idea; but it turns out that the symmetry of $\pm 47$ is very useful.

There are $95$ numbers in our list. Suppose that we choose $3$ of them. **Some** choices add up to $0$. Some choices have positive sum. Some have negative sum. **By symmetry**, just as many have positive sum  as negative sum.

So if we find the number $z$ of choices with sum $0$, we will be finished. For let $p$ be the number with positive sum. We have $z+2p=\binom{95}{3}$. We solve for $p$, and find that our answer is
$$3!\frac{\binom{95}{3}-z}{2}.$$

Now we only want to find $z$, the number of unordered triples, or equivalently triples with $a\lt b\lt c$, such that $a$, $b$, and $c$ satisfy the size constraints, and $a+b+c =0$. Much simpler!

Temporarily, we leave it to you to find $z$. That is very doable.

**Finding $z$:** We concentrate on the **middle term**. If this is $0$, there are $47$ ways to complete the triple. Now look at middle term $1,2,3, \dots$. (There are just as many with middle terms $-1, -2,-3,\dots$.)

If the middle term is $1$, the big term can be any of $2$ to $46$, so $45$ possibilities, and now the small term is determined. If the middle term is $2$, there are $43$ possibilities, and so on until when the middle term is $23$, there is only $1$ possibility for the big term, namely $24$. So the total with positive middle term is $1+3+5+\cdots +45$, which is $23^2$.  It follows that
$$z=47+(2)(23^2),$$
and we are finished.

**Remark:** Precisely the same reasoning works if we replace the bound $\pm 47$ by $\pm B$.  One can also deal with intervals that are less overtly symmetric. But the symmetry or near symmetry of the condition  $a+b+c$ is crucial for an argument of the above type.

Answer (score 5):

There’s a better way: introduce $d_1=282-(a_1+b_1+c_1)$ and count solutions to

$$a_1+b_1+c_1+d_1=282$$

subject to the known constraints on $a_1,b_1$, and $c_1$ and the constraint $0\le d_1\le 140$.

Comment: Neat, I've solved it. Thanks

Comment: @John: Great. You’re welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Let $N = 47$ and $X = \{-N,\ldots,N\}$. We have $|X^3| = |X|^3 = (2N+1)^3$.

Let $\mathscr{N}_{???}$ be the number of solutions for any equation ??? involving $(a,b,c) \in X^3$.
Because of symmetry,

$$\mathscr{N}_{a+b+c>0} = \mathscr{N}_{a+b+c<0} \implies \mathscr{N}_{a+b+c>0} = \frac12 \left((2N+1)^3 - \mathscr{N}_{a+b+c=0} \right)$$

For any fixed $c$, the number of solutions for $a + b + c = 0$ is $(2N+1) - |c|$, we have:

$$\mathscr{N}_{a+b+c=0} = \sum_{c = -N}^{N} \left( (2N+1) - |c|\,\right) = (2N+1)^2 -2\frac{N(N+1)}{2} = 3N^2+3N+1$$

and hence

$$\mathscr{N}_{a+b+c>0} = \frac12\left((2N+1)^3 - (3N^2+3N+1)\right) = \frac12 N (8N^2 + 9N + 3) = 425303$$

**Method 2**

Another way to get the same answer is try to attack a more general question:

> Given $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $d, L \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$, what is the
>   number of integer solutions for $a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_d = n$
>   where all $ 0 \le a_i < L$.

Let $\varphi_{d}(n)$ and $\varphi_{d}(n;L)$ be the number of non-negative integer solutions  where $\sum_{i=1}^{d} a_i = n$ and those with further restriction that $a_1,\ldots,a_d < L$. i.e.

$$\begin{align}
\varphi_{d}(n) 
&= \left|\,\{ (a_i) \in \mathbb{N}^{d} : \sum_{i=1}^{d} a_i = n \}\,\right|\\
\varphi_{d}(n;L)
&= \left|\,\{ (a_i) \in \mathbb{N}^{d} : \sum_{i=1}^{d} a_i = n \wedge a_1, \ldots a_d < L \}\,\right|
\end{align}$$

By induction, it is not hard to show:

$$\varphi_{d}(n) = \begin{cases}\binom{n+d-1}{d} = \frac{n(n+1)\cdots(n+d-1)}{d!},& n \ge 0\\ \\0, & n < 0\end{cases}$$

To compute $\varphi_{d}(n;L)$, we can start with the set of solutions for $\varphi_{d}(n)$
and then proceed to remove those solutions with at least one $x_i \ge L$. For first approximation, we get:

$$\begin{align}\varphi_{d}(n;L) 
&= \varphi_{d}(n) - \sum_{j=1}^{d} \left|\{ (a_i) \in \mathbb{Z}^d : \sum_{i=1}^{d} a_i = n \wedge a_j \ge L \}\right| + \cdots\\
&= \varphi_{d}(n) - d \varphi_{d}(n-L) + \cdots\\
\end{align}$$

However, for those solutions with at least two $a_i \ge L$, this procedure removed it more than once. We need to add back their contribution. For second approximation, we get:

$$\begin{align}\varphi_{d}(n;L)
&= \varphi_{d}(n) - d \varphi_{d}(n-L) + \sum_{1 \le j < k \le d} \left|\{(a_i) \in \mathbb{Z}^d : \sum_{i=1}^{d} a_i = n \wedge a_j, a_k \ge L \}\right| + \cdots\\
&= \varphi_{d}(n) - d \varphi_{d}(n-L) + \binom{d}{2} \varphi_{d}(n-2L) + \cdots
\end{align}$$

For those solutions with at least three $a_i \ge L$, this again add back too much. We can use Inclusion-Exclusion to organize this mess. In the end, we will have:

$$\varphi_{d}(n;L) 
= \sum_{k=0}^{d} (-1)^k \binom{d}{k} \varphi_{d}(n - kL)
= \sum_{k=0}^{\min(d,\lfloor\frac{n}{L}\rfloor)}(-1)^k \binom{d}{k} \varphi_{d}(n-kL)
$$

Back to our original problem, it is clear the number of solutions for 
$$a + b + c < 0,\quad|a|, |b|, |c| \le N$$
is equal to the number of solutions for $$x + y + z = 3N,\quad 0 \le x, y, z < 2N+1$$
Since $\lfloor\frac{3N}{2N+1}\rfloor = 1$, we get:

$$\begin{align}\mathscr{N}_{a+b+c>0}
&= \mathscr{N}_{a+b+c<0}\\
&= \varphi_3(3N;2N+1)\\
&= \varphi_3(3N) - \binom{3}{1}\varphi_3(3N-(2N+1))\\
&= \varphi_3(3N) - 3\varphi_3(N-1)\\
&= \frac12 N(3N+1)(3N+2)) - \frac12 (N-1)N(N+1)\\
&= \frac12 N(8N^2+9N+3)\\
&= 425303
\end{align}$$

**UPDATE**

Oops, forget the requirement that $a, b, c$ are distinct. We need to count the
cases where $a, b, c$ fails to be distinct. There are two possible cases:

- ***Case 1***, two of $a, b, c$ is the same. There are 3 possible subcases.
  For the subcase where $a = b \ne c$, we have $2N(2N+1)$ combination. 
  $2 \lfloor\frac{N}{2}\rfloor$ of which sums to $0$.
  The other 2 subcases give same amount of counting.
- ***Case 2***. $a = b = c$. There are $2N+1$ combination, only 1 of them sums to $0$.

From this, the number of solutions for $a + b + c > 0$ with $a \ne b \ne c$ is given by:

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{N}^{distinct}_{a+b+c>0} &= \mathscr{N}_{a+b+c>0} - \frac12\left( (6N+1)(2N+1) - 6\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\rfloor - 1\right)\\
&= \frac12 (N-1)N(8N+5) + 3\lfloor\frac{N}{2}\rfloor\\
&= 411930
\end{align}$$

Comment: I think the number is not quite right, but close.

Comment: @AndréNicolas brute force counting does give me 425303. What is your number?

Comment: Ooh, I see. I miss the part that $a, b, c$ need to be distinct...

Comment: Have forgotten, $41\dots$ I think. The number **must** be divisible by $6$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I get 411930 for the number of solutions with distinct $a, b, c$ (confirmed by brute force searching). However the approach is no longer elegant :-(

Answer (score 1):

We argue about the set $A_n$ of admissible lattice points in the "cube" $[-n,n]^3\cap{\mathbb Z}^3$. Note that $A_1=\emptyset$ and $A_{n-1}\subset A_n$ for $n\geq2$. Denote the number of points in $A_n$ by $f(n)$.

We begin with $f(2)$. The set $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$ contains four triples of different numbers  with a positive sum, namely $\{2,1,0\}$, $\{2,1,-1\}$, $\{2,1,-2\}$, $\{2,0,-1\}$. It follows that $f(2)=24$.

We now count the number of points in the set $\Delta_n:=A_n\setminus A_{n-1}$. Draw a cube, and you will see that $\Delta_n$ consists of three "quadratic plates" from which a triangle has been taken away, and three little triangles of exactly the same size. Doing a careful count with the plate $c=n$ and the little triangle on the face $c=-n$ one obtains
$$\#\Delta_n=\cases{3(4n^2-5n+2)\quad &($n$ even) \cr
3(4n^2-5n+1)&($n$ odd)\cr}\ .\tag{1}$$
The distinction between even and odd $n$ stems from the diagonal $a=b$ that has to be removed: If $n$ is even there is a point with $a+b=-n$ on this diagonal, and when $n$ is odd there is no such point.

Formula $(1)$ can be rewritten as
$$\#\Delta_n=12n^2 -15n +{9\over2}+{3\over2}(-1)^n\qquad(n\geq3)\ .$$
It follows that
$$f(n)=24+\sum_{k=3}^n\left(12n^2-15n+{9\over2}+{3\over2}(-1)^n\right)\ ,$$
and this evaluates to
$$f(n)={1\over4}\bigl(16 n^3-6n^2-4n-3+3(-1)^n\bigr)\qquad(n\geq2)\ .\tag{2}$$
Note that we even get $f(1)=0$, though in this case the counting might be considered somewhat fishy. (I have to admit that I also did a brute force count with Mathematica and  up to $n=47$ obtained the numbers produced by $(2)$.)

In particular $f(47)=411930$, in accordance with @André Nicolas' result (when unpacked) for this case.